# Consultar 2 tablas para ver que registros no estan en la segunda tabla y si no están, insertar un nuevo registro (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

lo que deseo hacer es validar si un registro existe en una tabla con un procedimiento almacenado desde SQL SERVER y si no lo hace insertar un nuevo registro.

Tengo una tabla comunicaciones y otra tabla comunicacionLlave, mi tabla comunicaciones tiene un atributo booleano que indica true si es para comunicacionLlave y esa tabla llave tiene un atributo idComunicacion que es una FK de Comunicaciones (donde es PK), me gustaria saber como hacer un sp que compruebe si hay un registro en mi tabla ComunicacionLlave que coincida con un registro de mi tabla Comunicaciones, y en caso de que no exista instertar un nuevo registro correspondiente en ComunicacionLlave

Comment: pues suena que usar `NOT EXISTS` sería la alternativa correcta

Comment: Gracias, voy probando!

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.